# Java/SWT: an error has occurred see log for more

Tags: java, swt

We are seeing this very generic error pop up in some circumstances, but we can't seem to track down what is generating it and I'm hoping someone has some insight into where to begin. We have multiple client machines all running the same version of our software, build with SWT, and all hitting the same server, but not everyone gets this error. Nothing is showing up in our client or server logs and I have no idea what log file this error may be referring to, so it's not an error that we are catching anywhere and we have no details about this. Since it's a pop-up message that leads me to think it may be an SWT error. I've seen people mention this error when using Eclipse, but I haven't found where anyone mentioned it in an application they built.

I know this is vague, but I don't have much more to go on. Does anyone have an idea where to start looking for culprits?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're building an RCP application?  In that case, this error is talking about the **Eclipse platform log**.

There should be a `.metadata\.log` file in your program's *instance location*.  If you do not know your instance location, you can query it by calling:

```
Platform.getInstanceLocation();
```

Comment: Grr, I'm getting The method getInstanceLocation() is undefined for the type Platform. We're on Eclipse 3.3.2, so I don't know if our version has this method, but I'll look for that log file.